# Why was this question about running Valorant on a Mac computer downvoted?

Tags: discussion, voting, specific-question

Here is the [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/407637/how-to-get-valorant-on-2021-m1-macbook-air) — [How to get VALORANT on 2021 M1 MacBook Air](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/407637/4797):

> VALORANT, currently, is not on MacOS. It is also not on Steam. You
> cannot download VALORANT through the website because... well, there's
> no button to do so. So how do you get it on Mac?
>
> Originally, I thought about using Mac's built in Bootcamp partition,
> but that doesn't work, because the Mac is a 2021 M1 MacBook Air
> (meaning not a intel-based, dubbed 'silicon' instead).
>
> I found out that, apparently, you can do this:
>
> > M1 mac doesn't support boot camp and it will never support bootcamp.
> > Apple silicon Mac have a new Start Up options feature. You can install
> > any OS you want on it and do multi boot. There are no restriction from
> > Apple.
> > -https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253556967?answerId=257171239022#257171239022
> > (ShunnyBunny)
>
> If that's true, how do you do this? Is it good for gaming?
>
> Assuming you can't do that, are there any other ways to get it? Maybe
> another Windows emulator?

The tags were [macos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) and [valorant](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valorant).

I don't see any reason why it would be downvoted. It's not opionated, and while any possible answers of how to do so could get you banned from the game, it's still a useful question, just so someone could see, "Oh, anything I try will (at the time the question was written) get me banned. I'd better not try!"

Comment: The common sentiment on these sites is that downvotes are the result of the whims of individual users, and unless a person states their own reasons directly, it's often an exercise in futility trying to determine the reason from the outside.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yeah, but there'll generally be at least some common ideas about why it's bad. Also, if it violates the policy in some way, then it'll be pretty easy to see how and be able to tell me.

Comment: Note that if you hover over the downvote button, it gives this tooltip: _This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, I downvoted the question because a quick research would have told you that VALORANT can only be played on PC. End of the line.

The official site even tried to tell you, since there is no download button if you access their site on a MacOS.

On Arqade, a lot of users will downvote questions if it feels like you haven't done the smallest bit of research before posting. And that's where the question fails for me; it's pretty obvious as to why it won't run in Mac, it's not made for it; a quick glance to the specs page would have told you it's Windows only.

[image]

Comment: I take it running Windows games on Linux/a Steam deck using Proton is also not covered in that case (depending on your hardware, it may not react the same way for everyone).

Comment: Would guess both options are off the table for valorant. I know it doesnt run on linux too (just like mac, for the anticheat) and steam deck I would guess that if a game is not on steam, you can't run it on a vanilla deck